# How can I put the result of the counter into the cards on top of an html page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

For my project I've created a comparison script with Groovyscript to compare 2 different files. Within the Groovyscript I've added HTML that uses CSS and eventually Bootstrap(whatever version).

I've already managed to have my counters with a title on top of my HTML page, but it's not dynamic/responding. When you change the width and height of the page the layout is smashed. I've read that Bootstrap/CSS can help with re-arranging the page when the resolution changes. Therefore I was attracted to use cards. That worked fine, but still when the page becomes bigger or smaller the layout is off.

```html
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>
        <title>GroovyCardsBootstrap</title>    
        <style>   
        h{color:#86BEB6; font-size:50px;}
        * {box-sizing: border-box;}
        body {font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;}
        /* Float 4 columns side by side 
        .column4 {float: left;width: 15%;padding: 0 20px;position:absolute; top:10px; right:5px;}
        .column3 {float: left;width: 15%;padding: 0 20px;position:absolute; top:10px; right:205px;}
        .column2 {float: left;width: 15%;padding: 0 20px;position:absolute; top:10px; right:405px;}
        .column1 {float: left;width: 15%;padding: 0 20px;position:absolute; top:10px; right:605px;}*/
        /* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
        .row {margin: 0 -3px;}
        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row:after {
            content: '';display: table;clear: both;
            }
        .card {
            display:inline-block;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            }
        .card-group [class*='col-']{
            float:none;}
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class='card-group'>
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-block'>
                    <img class='card-text'  src='FODBosa.png'  alt='FodBosa.png' width='400' height='150' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='card' style='flex-grow: 3'>
                <div class='card-block'>
                    <span class='card-text' style='padding:0 5px'>Text 2</span><span class='card-text' style='padding:0 5px'>More text 2</span><span class='card-text' style='padding:0 5px'>More text 2</span>
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h>Test results comparison KBO with PDC</h>
        <div style = 'border:1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;'>
            <p>Automated tests are executed in ReadyAPI. These are the results of the comparison on the responses between KBO and PDC</p>
        </div>"
```

After this, the Groovyscript is running ending with these lines to write:

```html
outputFile.append "<div class='card-group'><div class='card' style='background-color:black; color:white;'><div class='card-block'> <h3>Not found in KBO</h3> <p>" +notInPDCCounter+ "</p></div></div>"
    outputFile.append "<div class='card-group'><div class='card' style='background-color:#DA4747;'><div class='card-block'> <h3>Failed - PDC not same as KBO</h3>  <p>" +hasDifferences+ "</p></div> </div>"
    outputFile.append "<div class='card-group'><div class='card' style='background-color:#ff8080;'><div class='card-block'> <h3>Total lines read</h3>    <p>"+ failed + "</p></div></div>"
    outputFile.append "<div class='card-group'><div class='card' style='background-color:#52DA69;'><div class='card-block'> <h3>Passed - Info is in PDC</h3>    <p>" +(totalTotal-failed)+ "</p></div> </div> </div>"
```

The outputFile.append is giving me beautiful placed boxes under my paragraph at the beginning of the html page (I needed to insert the code into HTML for you to be able to see it, so the outcome is not ok)  but I actually would like those answers in the card itself that I've created in the beginning (see the one next to <img>.) How could I put the result of the counters, that are generated with the groovy script in the middle of all this, and thus only giving result at the end, in the top right card please? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got this right:

You are trying to display 4 cards in the top right corner of the page, side by side?
And you would like for these cards to be responsive at different vw?

I am not familiar with Groovy, but if you can wrap your cards into a div (or target the div through id or such), then you could use CSS Grid (for responsiveness) to create a 4-column grid and set the width of each column so they go in a new row as the width gets smaller.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Hello Erika, thanks for your answer. Yes, I want my cards side by side on top of the HTML page on the right. And yes I though about it to use id's but I don't know how to do that. Can you help me please to make that id-reference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've find it out with the tip of Erika Ravazollo:

I've put this JQuery script on the bottom of the page (within the body of course!)

```
outputFile.append "<script> \$('#source').appendTo('#destination');</script>"
```

Apparently for Groovyscript you need to ommit the dollar sign with a backslash. I don't know wy though.
In the part where I define my cards for the top I insert the destination:

```
        <div class='card' style='flex-grow: 3' id='destination'></div>
```

and I deleted the span tags

And in the part where I define my cards I add them as source:

```
<div class='card-block' id='source'>....</div>
```

I've trimmed the boxes a little bit for myself as in my example I gave you, you will see a box in a box in a box.  :-)